# Can I execute python code on a list simultaneous instead of sequential?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

First of all thank you for taking your time to read through this post. I'd like to begin that I'm very new to programming in general and that I seek advice to solve a problem.

I'm trying to create a script that checks if the content of a html page has been changed. I'm doing this to monitor certain website pages for changes. I've managed to find a script and I have made some alterations that it will go through a list of URL's checking if the page has been changed. The problem here is that its checking the page sequential. This means that it will go through the list checking the URL's one by one while I want the script to run the URL's parallel. I'm also using a while loop to continue checking the pages because even if a change took place it will still have to monitor the page. I could write a thousand more words on explaining what i'm trying to do so therefor have a look at the code:

```
import requests
import time
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import hashlib
from urllib.request import urlopen


url = ["https://www.youtube.be", "https://www.google.com", "https://www.google.be"]
i = 0
response = urlopen(url[i]).read()
currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()


while True:

    try:
       response = urlopen(url[i]).read()
       currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()
       print('checking')
       time.sleep(10)
       response = urlopen(url[i]).read()
       newHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()
       i +=1

       if newHash == currentHash:
          continue

       else:

          print('Change detected')
          print (url[i])
          time.sleep(10)
          continue


    except Exception as e:

          i = 0
          print('resetting increment')
          continue
```

Comment: It seems what you need is parallel processing. check `ThreadPoolExecutor` https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called multi-threading.

Conceptually this is how it works:

```
import hashlib
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen
import threading

# Define a function for the thread
def f(url):
    initialHash = None

    while True:
        response = urlopen(url).read()
        currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()
        if not initialHash:
            initialHash = currentHash

        if currentHash != initialHash:
            print('Change detected')
            print (url)
            time.sleep(10)
            continue

    return

# Create two threads as follows
for url in ["https://www.youtube.be", "https://www.google.com", "https://www.google.be"]:
    t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(url,))
    t.start()
```

Comment: better! another nitpick: t should be stored in a list so join can be called to wait for all threads to finish (in a second loop of course)

Comment: also threads are okay when there are blocking calls that do not hog the cpu, but with pure python processing, processes are the only way to make sure everything executes in parallel. threads are the way to do it in this example of course

Comment: Hi Gab, Thanks a lot for answering. I've applied the concept of multi-threading into the script but I'm running into some issues executing the loop. I've named my function tollercheck: line 13, in tollercheck currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest() UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment I think its not able to get the response of the hash now that its inside its function. it is showing this behavior on all three threads.

Comment: @izomac you need the entire logic in the thread. I updated the example to add your logic to compare the initial and latest hash. It's shorter than your version but it does the same thing. You may want to add again the try/except to catch loading errors.

Comment: @Gab and Jean-François Fabre Thanks a lot for this solution. it seems to work as intended =)

Answer (score 0):

Running example of OP code Using Thread Executor

**Code**

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import requests
import hashlib
from urllib.request import urlopen

def check_change(url):
    '''
        Checks for a change in web page contents by comparing current to previous hash
    '''
    try:
        response = urlopen(url).read()
        currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()
        
        time.sleep(10)
        response = urlopen(url).read()
        newHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()

        if newHash != currentHash:
            return "Change to:", url
        else:
            return None
        
    except Exception as e:
        return "Error", e, url
           
page_urls = ["https://www.youtube.be", "https://www.google.com", "https://www.google.be"]

while True:
     # We can use a Thread Execution Manager to ensure threads are clean up properly
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        futures = []

        # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(check_change, url): url for url in page_urls}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            # Output result of each thread upon it's completion
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                status = future.result()
                if status:
                    print(*status)
                else:
                    print(f'No change to: {url}')
                    
            except Exception as exc:
                print('Site %r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
                
        time.sleep(10)  # Wait 10 seconds before rechecking sites
```

**Output**

```
Change to: https://www.google.com
Change to: https://www.google.be
Change to: https://www.youtube.be
Change to: https://www.google.be
Change to: https://www.google.com
Change to: https://www.youtube.be
Change to: https://www.google.be
Change to: https://www.google.com
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I've tested it and it works as intended. I did like the build in 'security' of having a maximum of 5 workers to not overload the CPU. I've learned a lot from analysing the code.

Thank you =)